# How do I transform Googles Alert RSS to live RSS XML format?

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, google-alerts

I wonder which smart folk can answer my query today.

I am using a WP plugin called RSS Post Importer.

I have setup Google Alerts at Google Alerts and I have the following RSS link from their RSS icon: https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/13358169444187985072/403372099919857275

The question: How do I change this RSS feed to an XML formatted link like e.g. 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business-11428889/rss.xml' ?

Even though the BBC rss doesnt work with this plugin I have, it does however work with another plugin which I believe it's because this other plugin only accepts a feed with a '.xml' extension at the end of the URL.

Thanks in advance,
Chappie

Answer (score 0):

After setting up the RSS feed, you might have to wait for the RSS feed to be loaded the first time. With less popular keywords, your RSS feed might even stay empty.

If you don't see the updated XML tag, then you won't see any  tags either.

This is what you want to see:

```
  <updated>2018-11-09T18:00:00Z</updated>
```

This is what you might see only:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:idx="urn:atom-extension:indexing">
<id>
tag:google.com,2005:reader/user/05244909058385793377/state/com.google/alerts/4925768041195115078
</id>
<title>Google Alert - mifid ii</title>
<link href="https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/05244909058385793377/4925768041195115078" rel="self"/>
</feed>
```

This is a RSS feed with two entries after the first load time. It worked for me instantly after playing impatiently with the settings:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:idx="urn:atom-extension:indexing">
    <id>
    tag:google.com,2005:reader/user/05244909058385793377/state/com.google/alerts/4925768041195115078
    </id>
    <title>Google Alert - mifid ii</title>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/05244909058385793377/4925768041195115078" rel="self"/>
    <updated>2018-11-09T18:00:00Z</updated>
    <entry>
    <id>
    tag:google.com,2013:googlealerts/feed:237107289461798771
    </id>
    <title type="html">
    <b>MiFID II</b>: ESMA Issues Latest Double Volume Cap Data
    </title>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.mondovisione.com/media-and-resources/news/mifid-ii-esma-issues-latest-double-volume-cap-data-6/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyHmVlMjUwY2E4NGMxNWQyZWM6Y28udWs6ZW46R0I6Ug&usg=AFQjCNEZb7H4tMRJBtVzwk16uCkc49DG4A"/>
    <published>2018-11-09T18:00:00Z</published>
    <updated>2018-11-09T18:00:00Z</updated>
    <content type="html">
    The European Securities and Markets Authority (ESMA) has updated today its public register with the latest set of double volume cap (DVC) data&nbsp;...
    </content>
    <author>
    <name/>
    </author>
    </entry>
    <entry>
    <id>
    tag:google.com,2013:googlealerts/feed:17979086610334644596
    </id>
    <title type="html">
    ESMA Launches Call For Evidence On Periodic Auctions For Equity Instruments
    </title>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://www.mondovisione.com/media-and-resources/news/esma-launches-call-for-evidence-on-periodic-auctions-for-equity-instruments/&ct=ga&cd=CAIyHmVlMjUwY2E4NGMxNWQyZWM6Y28udWs6ZW46R0I6Ug&usg=AFQjCNEkrCnUpLB-5icFrWykHs90H-wCxw"/>
    <published>2018-11-09T10:30:00Z</published>
    <updated>2018-11-09T10:30:00Z</updated>
    <content type="html">
    Following the introduction of <b>MiFID II</b>/MiFIR on 3 January, a new type of periodic auction trading system for equity instruments consisting of auctions of&nbsp;...
    </content>
    <author>
    <name/>
    </author>
    </entry>
    </feed>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you click on the little rss icon in your google alert page, it takes you to a page which displays the xml page... at least that is what it looks like to me.